# Confused with a system of equations with three variables that has infinitely many solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, intuition

I'm studying High School Algebra and it had this question:

> Solve the system by equations:
>
> \begin{align*}   x + y - z &= \,0 \\    2x + 4y - 2z &= 6 \\    3x +
>  6y - 3z &= \,9 \end{align*}

The solution was:

> infinitely many solutions (x, 3, z) where x = z − 3; y = 3; z is any real number

I've spent hours on the problem. The textbook just gave a vague explanation and I can't seem to get how it works. Can someone please intuitively explain how this is?

Comment: The third equation is $\dfrac32$ times the second, so isn't independent; it's like two equations, three unknowns

Comment: Each equation is a plane, but the plane of the second equation is the same as the plane of the third equation. So the solution of the system is the intersection of two planes: a line, which has infinitely many points.

Comment: @ajotatxe but what does "where x = z - 3; y = 3; z is any real number" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Dividing the second equation by $2$ and the third by $3$ we get
$$x+y-z=0$$
$$x+2y-z=3$$
$$x+2y-z=3$$
the second and the third equation are the same.
Multiplying the first equation by $-1$ and adding to the second we get $y=3$.
Plgging this into the first and second equation we get
$$x-z=-3$$
$$x-z=-3$$ so we obtain the solutions
$$x,3,x+3$$

Comment: But what does the part "where x = z - 3; y = 3; z is any real number" mean? How come it's included in the solution?

Comment: I have added some lines for you!

Comment: But then couldn't we also say that the solution is (z - 3, 3, x + 3)?

Comment: The solution set must contain only one parameter.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm asking such basic questions but what does that mean? Is that a rule?

Comment: Yes, write your solution set so like i have written above.

Comment: What rule is that called?

Comment: It is the parameter representation of the solution, in your case only one parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If $x,y,x\in\mathbb R$ are such that $2x+4y-2z=6$, then $\frac32(2x+4y-2z)=\frac32\times6$; in other words, $3x+6y-3z=9$, which is the thir equation. Therefore, solving that system is the same thing as solving the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x+y-z=0\\2x+4y-2z=6,\end{array}\right.$$which is equivalent to$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x+y=z\\2x+4y=2z+6.\end{array}\right.$$Solving this system, you will get the solutions that you mentioned.

Comment: But what does the part "where x = z - 3; y = 3; z is any real number" mean? How come it's included in the solution?

Comment: As I wrote, if you solve my last system, you will get that $x=z-3$ and that $y=3$. Therefore, the set of all solutions is the set of all triples $(z-3,3,z)$, with $z\in\mathbb R$.